# Are there more い adjectives or more だ adjectives?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

Learning adjectives, I knew there are two major groups of adjectives 
い and だ. I am wondering, which group has more adjectives?

Comment: I don't have source but the だ group is more productive because it can convert virtually all the nouns into an adjective.

Comment: The い group has been handed down to us from the antiquity, while many of the だ group adjectives are formulated from nouns, as @user4092 remarked. I don't know which is the majority, as I have never counted. But I guess the だ group *eventually* outnumbers the い group.

Answer (score 1):

na/-no adjectives in total seem to outnumber -i adjectives.

Values retrieved from [WWWJDIC](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/wwwjdicinf.html) dictionary file:

i-Adjectives: 2895, 268 of which is listed as a "common word";
na-Adjectives: 6759, 1425 of which is listed as a "common word";
no-Adjectives: 10832, 2799 of which is listed as a "common word".

Probably because of how, like user4092 mentioned, the na-no group can virtually convert all nouns into "adjectives".

Comment: wow, you seriously don't need to hit jisho.org to get this data. You can get it for free from Jim Breen (http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/wwwjdicinf.html)

Comment: nice, thanks for referring me to that. I'll parse through that again and update my numbers.